# Does Harmon.ie support external content types and BCS

Tags: harmon.ie

In SharePoint you can create external content types using the Business Data Connectivity Service.

Does Harmon.ie support/works with these type of (standard) site columns?

Regards,

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BCS types will show up in harmon.ie property editor as "Edit this column on server" - this behavior is by design, harmon.ie property does not support BCS columns.